# How can I call a function in asp.net mvc in a way that the system does not wait for its response or till it returns the control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, async-await

I am new to asp.net mvc. I want to call a function. it is basically used for backend work. It is a long process so i do not want the system to stop till the function completes. (The function does some pre-processing on text and stores the data in database so i do not want it to return any thing to me)
Is there a way that my system does not have to wait for it and continues its work after the function has been called?
I have tried the async Action method but i could not do it as I couldn't understand it.

Comment: You could call an async method without awaiting it, but that's generally a bad idea.  Do understand that this kind of "fire and forget" methodology includes the "forget" part.  Which means if the operation fails in any way you wouldn't know.  It seems likely that there's a much better way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Does the user know this long process is taking place? I ask because if the user expects something and he doesn't see any feedback, he may click again and trigger your process several times, and I guess that's not something you would like.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `Task.Run(() =>｛ do your job here...｝)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ***async*** modifier on a method, it's referred to as an async method.

For more details, please visit:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx